# Identifying partner changes across columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm dealing with a longitudinal dataset and am interested in identifying when individuals who divorce marry new partners. My dataset looks like this:

```
data.frame(
  t1 = c(100, 000, 000, 103, 000, 106), 
  t2 = c(000, 000, 102, 103, 105, 000), 
  t3 = c(000, 000, 102, 103, 000, 128), 
  t4 = c(100, 000, 121, 103, 000, 000), 
  t5 = c(100, 101, 121, 103, 105, 130)
  )
```

Which produces the following:

```
   t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
1 100   0   0 100 100
2   0   0   0   0 101
3   0 102 102 121 121
4 103 103 103 103 103
5   0 105   0   0 105
6 106   0 128   0 130
```

Each row indicates a person. Each column indicates a point in time. Each value indicates the number of their partner at that time. What makes this analysis complicated is that there are zeros for individuals who are single, divorced, or who did not participate in that wave of data collection.

What I want to know is the time when a person acquires a new partner AFTER they divorce. Ideally I'd get a data frame with t - 1 columns that looks like this:

```
  t12 t23 t34 t45
1   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   1   0
4   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0
6   0   1   0   1
```

Where 1 indicates that a person married a new partner between waves. So, person 3 married a new person between waves 3 and 4. And person 6 married a new person between waves 2 and 3 as well as between 4 and 5.

The issue I am running into is that my attempts to identify these changes cannot distinguish between a partner shift (e.g., person 3's partner shift from 102 to 121) and a shift from no data to some data (e.g., person 3's shift from 0 to 102), or a shift from some data to no data (e.g., person 1's shift from 100 to 0).

Comment: Is it possible to recode the "missing" (i.e `0`) data to be more informative? The value of `0` equaling missing data AND divorce at the same time is extremely problematic (and bad study design). Ideally missing should be `NA`. This is the actual issue IMO because person 6 could potentially have had 5 partners at 5 different time points. Did they divorce twice (so they have 3 partners) or did they actually divorce 4 times (5 partners)?

Comment: Do you assume that it doesn't count as a second marriage if you didn't observe a previous marriage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `tidyverse` suite of packages.  The basic idea is to label the rows with an individual-specific label, reshape the data to a "long" format, get rid of the 0s, then work on each individual at a time.

For each individual, we make sure that the data point isn't a duplicate and isn't the same as the first data point (which will be non-zero because we removed all the zeros).  After that, we just have to convert everything back to the original wide format, and remove/relabel the appropriate columns.

```
new_df <- df %>%
  mutate(individual = 1:length(t1)) %>%
  gather(time_point, status, -individual) %>%
  mutate(
    status = if_else(status == 0, NA_integer_, status %>% as.integer())
  ) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(individual) %>%
  mutate(
    status = ((status != status[1]) & !duplicated(status))*1
  ) %>%
  spread(time_point, status, fill = 0) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-individual, -t1, t12 = t2, t23 = t3, t34 = t4, t45 = t5)
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. The only thing I will note is that this approach deletes rows where all data is missing (i.e., all 0s). However, I merged this output with the original data frame, which resolved that issue.

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  I wasn't sure if you would have cases with all 0s or not, but merging back would be my solution for that issue as well.